# NodeJS child processes are terminated on SIGINT

Tags: node.js, linux, process, terminate

Im creating NodeJS application, that creates quite a few child processes. They are started by both `spawn` and `exec` (based on lib implementation). Some examples may be GraphicsMagick (`gm`) for image manipulation or Tesseract (`node-tesseract`) for OCR. Now I would like to gracefully end my application so I created shutdown hook:

```
function exitHandler() {
    killer.waitForShutdown().then(function(){
        logger.logInfo("Exited successfully.");
        process.exit();
    }).catch(function(err) {
        logger.logError(err, "Error during server shutdown.");
        process.exit();
    });
}

process.on('exit', exitHandler);
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler);
process.on('SIGTERM', exitHandler);
```

Exit handling itself works fine, it is waiting well and so on, but there is a catch. All "native" (gm, tesseract, ...) processes that run at that time are also killed. Exception messages only consists of "Command failed" and then content of command which failed e.g.

```
"Command failed: /bin/sh -c tesseract tempfiles/W1KwFSdz7MKdJQQnUifQFKdfTRDvBF4VkdJgEvxZGITng7JZWcyPYw6imrw8JFVv/ocr_0.png /tmp/node-tesseract-49073e55-0ef6-482d-8e73-1d70161ce91a -l eng -psm 3\nTesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica"
```

So at least for me, they do not tell anything useful. I'm also queuing process execution, so PC don't get overloaded by 50 processes at one time. When running processes are killed by SIGINT, new processes that were queued are started just fine and finishes successfully. I have problem only with those few running at the time of receiving SIGINT. This behavior is same on Linux (Debian 8) and Windows (W10). From what I read here, people usually have opposite problem (to kill child processes). I tried to search if stdin gets somehow piped into child processes but I can't find it. So is this how its supposed to work? Is there any trick to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because, by default, the `detached` option is set to `false`. If `detached` is `false`, the signals will also be sent to the child processes, regardless of whether you setup an event listener.

To stop this happening, you need to change your `spawn` calls to use the third argument in order to specify `detached`; for example:

```
spawn('ls', ['-l'], { detached: true })
```

From the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached):

> On Windows, setting options.detached to true makes it possible for the
>   child process to continue running after the parent exits. The child
>   will have its own console window. Once enabled for a child process, it
>   cannot be disabled.
>
> On non-Windows platforms, if options.detached is set to true, the
>   child process will be made the leader of a new process group and
>   session. Note that child processes may continue running after the
>   parent exits regardless of whether they are detached or not. See
>   setsid(2) for more information.